# Activate text hover on image hover

Tags: jquery, hover

The title of the projects has a border-bottom on hover, I want that it shows also when I hover over the image of the project not just when I hover over the text.

I tried with css with no luck.

Comment: Can you please shortly share your code?

Comment: Get some friends man! get a real life behind that computer you nerd! Well that would be hard to get looking like this right: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/25515230.jpg   such a sad life you must have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery hover event. On hovering the image, in the callback you can use the following code :

```
$(".link1").css("text-decoration","underline");
```